# How are dependent keys registered? (Key-Value Observing)

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-bindings, key-value-observing

I have created a simple Cocoa Application.  In MainMenu.xib I have added an NSDatePicker and an NSTextField.  Both of these objects have Value bindings to properties of the App Delegate.  I expect that when the user changes the date in the NSDatePicker, the NSTextField will be updated.  This isn't happening.  Here is the App Delegate:

```
//  AppDelegate.h
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *dateFromPicker;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *dateString;

@end


//  AppDelegate.m
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{

}

- (NSString *)dateString
{
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    return [formatter stringFromDate:self.dateFromPicker];
}

+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingDateString
{
    return [NSSet setWithObject:@"dateFromPicker"];
}

@end
```

Updated code with an observer for dateFromPicker and some NSLog statements:

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"dateFromPicker" options:0 context:NULL];
    self.dateFromPicker = [NSDate dateWithNaturalLanguageString:@"12/12/12"];
}

- (NSString *)dateString
{
    NSLog(@"dateString was called.");
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    return [formatter stringFromDate:self.dateFromPicker];
}

+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingDateString
{
    NSLog(@"keyPathsForValuesAffectingDateString was called.");
    return [NSSet setWithObject:@"dateFromPicker"];
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:         (NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    NSLog(@"dateFromPicker changed.");
}

@end
```

Here is the log:

```
2012-08-10 15:37:15.086 ... keyPathsForValuesAffectingDateString was called.
2012-08-10 15:37:15.087 ... dateString was called.
2012-08-10 15:37:15.116 ... dateFromPicker changed.
2012-08-10 15:37:15.117 ... dateString was called.
2012-08-10 15:37:19.831 ... dateFromPicker changed.
2012-08-10 15:37:19.831 ... dateString was called.
```

Comment: I have discovered that the above code works fine, until it is put in a subclass of NSArrayController.  That is where it was originally in my project, but I created a simple project to work through this problem.  So there must be something about the NSArrayController class that affects KVO.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not exactly what you were asking, but ...

Why don't you bind the NSTextField to the NSDate property and add a formatter to it in Interface Builder?

Comment: That would work, but I'm really trying to understand dependent keys better.  I created this example as a way to ask the question and hopefully get an explanation of why this doesn't work.

Comment: Well, I see nothing suspect in the code. Try setting up an observer and see if it fires (if so, it's something related to the bindings, not the KVO). Also try to change the date from code instead of using the picker and see if it fires. And maybe add a few printouts to log so you can trace what happens when.